# Android - WakeLock - POST location on PUSH notification received when screen lock'd (parse.com)

Tags: android, parse-platform, locationmanager, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I want to **POST** my **Location** on **PushReceived** when the screen is lock'd.
My code works when the screen is **on**.
WakeLock does not seem to work...

When receiving a **PUSH notification** for the **first time** from ***Parse.com*** the screen turns **ON** and I can see that the **GPS** ***icon*** pops up. And the database updates.

But the second time I get a PUSH notfication the **onLocationCanged** is not triggered, and the POST never gets sendt. Why is this ? However the screen turns on, and the GPS icon is shown.

Evrytime I set debug at this point it works:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

Some sort of asynch tastk problem maby ?

Here is my code:

```
public class PushNotificationReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver implements  LocationListener{

        @Override    
        public void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                //WakeLock
                pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((pm.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | pm.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | pm.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
                wakeLock.acquire();

                JSONObject pushData;
                String alert = null;
                String title = null;
                try {
                    pushData = new JSONObject(intent.getStringExtra(PushNotificationReceiver.KEY_PUSH_DATA));
                    alert = pushData.getString("alert");
                    title = pushData.getString("title");
                } catch (JSONException e) {}

                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                //Getting LOCATION
                getLocation(context, locationManager);

                Intent cIntent = new Intent(PushNotificationReceiver.ACTION_PUSH_OPEN);
                cIntent.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
                cIntent.setPackage(context.getPackageName());

                PendingIntent pContentIntent =
                        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0 /*just for testing*/, cIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
                builder
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.car190)
                        .setContentTitle(alert)
                        .setContentText(title)
                        .setContentIntent(pContentIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);


                NotificationManager myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                myNotificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
            }


     private void getLocation(final Context context, final LocationManager locationManager){

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

            //Stop receiving LOCATION after 5 sec
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    locationManager.removeUpdates(PushNotificationReceiver.this);

                    //WakeLock release
                    wakeLock.release();
                }
            }, 5000);


         }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    currentLat = location.getLatitude() + "";
    currentLng = location.getLongitude() + "";
    currentDate = new Date();
    String username = tabFragment1.usernameResponse;

    try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(username);
        myusername = object.getString("ID");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //POST to Database
    postLocation(mainActivity.getAppContext(), currentLat, currentLng, currentDate.toString(), myusername);
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
        //Stop receiving LOCATION after 5 sec
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                locationManager.removeUpdates(PushNotificationReceiver.this);

                //WakeLock release
                wakeLock.release();
            }
        }, 5000);
```

and add

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(PushNotificationReceiver.this);
wakeLock.release();
```

In **onLocationChanged**, like this:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    currentLat = location.getLatitude() + "";
    currentLng = location.getLongitude() + "";
    currentDate = new Date();
    username = tabFragment3.userEmail;

    postLocation(mainActivity.getAppContext(), currentLat, currentLng, currentDate.toString(), username);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(PushNotificationReceiver.this);
    wakeLock.release();
}
```